# I want to make my search bar a Popup window like the image?

Tags: css, popupwindow, searchbar

I am working on a site. But I am facing a problem related to the Search bar. I want to make my Search bar a popup window like the [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SBWj.jpg).

I think it may be possible through Javascript or Jquery but I am not expert in those languages that's why I couldn't do it and I need your help. So please help me. Thanks.

Comment: There is no help for me please.

Comment: what pop up window? I don't see any

Comment: there is no popup in the image you've provided. we can't see what you are trying to do

Comment: Oh. I have removed the link as I have solved it myself. Thank you for your comments. But if you want to see what I was speaking about then you can check this link: http://site4preview.site90.net/wordpress/ .

Comment: Aww man, I started typing my answer before you posted your last comment. Well, maybe it will help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need Javascript. In the site you linked to, this is achieved by these lines of CSS:

```
.site-header .search-field {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url(images/search-icon.png);
    background-position: 5px center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 24px 24px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 37px;
    margin: 3px 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 34px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: width 400ms ease, background 400ms ease;
    transition:         width 400ms ease, background 400ms ease;
    width: 0;
}

.site-header .search-field:focus {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #c3c0ab;
    cursor: text;
    outline: 0;
    width: 230px;
}
```

To explain:

The upper block sets the search field to `width: 0;`, effectively making it invisible except for the icon, which is in the padding. It also instructs the browser to animate any changes to width property with the `transition` lines.

The lower block has the pseudo element `:focus`, so it only comes into effect when the search field receives input focus (most commonly by clicking in it). Then it gets `width: 230px;`, making it pop out. As soon as it loses focus, it will disappear again, because the `width` goes back to `0`.

Comment: Right, it may help anybody else. Actually the site I linked, I am working on it and I did that but I did it through jquery and through jquery it is quite easy than the CSS. Also CSS transition may not work in all browsers. Anyway thanks for doing this.